# Cant find Google Map Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just come to know there is no Google Map Android API v2 available in google developers APIs menu,

http://s30.postimg.org/txz8319g1/image.png

Anybody has any idea what has happened ?

Comment: `Google Map Android API` exists. It is first under `Google Maps API` section.

Comment: I can see that but I need Google Map Android API v2. I had seen that 3-4 days back right there.

Comment: Maybe they just changed a name..

Comment: Yes, you are right @bjiang I implemented Google Map Android API instead of Google Map Android API v2 and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They just changed a name. Implemente `Google Map Android API` instead of `Google Map Android API v2` and it will work fine.